# How can I display my own Custom view on the Secondary display using cwac-presentation library?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have created a view with EditText and a Button and want to make this view display over the secondary display.I have used Mirroring fragment for this.
setMirror() is not setting the view on the Secondary Display.(It is coming as a black overlay).

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a view with EditText and a Button and want to make this view display over the secondary display.

Have your custom `Presentation` display it, that you tie into [a `PresentationHelper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation#usage-presentationhelper). Or, have [your custom `PresentationFragment`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation#usage-presentationfragment) display it.

> I have used Mirroring fragment for this.

That would only work if the widgets are shown on the primary display, in a `MirroringFrameLayout` or the equivalent.

Comment: Yes. My primary display shows my custom views.where as the secondary display don't.

Comment: @user3758881: I cannot help you much without seeing your code. Try [the demo app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation/tree/master/demo) and see if it works. If the demo app works, compare [its mirroring sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/preso/demo/MirrorPresentationActivity.java) with your mirroring code to see what differs. If you can create a sample project that reproduces the problem, file an issue and I can try to take a look at it.